# Creating a table view in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

'Missing Expression' for Select Distinct Query
[the error sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtX6V.png)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "KIR_V_KAS_MASUK_KET" ("...") as
    SELECT
KMH.KODE_KAS,
KA.NIS,
KA.NAMA,
KA.KELAS,
KA.JURUSAN,
        SELECT DISTINCT
        (SELECT PERIODE FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD WHERE KODE_KAS=:P16_KODE_KAS) PERIODE,
        TO_CHAR((SELECT SUM(PEMBAYARAN)  FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL WHERE KODE_KAS = :P16_KODE_KAS), '999,999,999') TOTAL_PEMBAYARAN,
         TO_CHAR(WAJIB_BAYAR * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KIR_ANGGOTA WHERE STATUS != 'TIDAK AKTIF'), '999,999,999') TOTAL_WAJIB_BAYAR,
KMD.KETERANGAN
FROM
KIR_ANGGOTA KA,
KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD KMH,
KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL KMD
WHERE
KMD.KODE_KAS=KMH.KODE_KAS
AND
KMD.NIS=KA.NIS
/
```

i wanted to make a view table with 9 column that 3 of those column are something that i think is the problem, because select distinct in a select query which is wrong but i really don't know the solution because i just add those 'select distinct' query without knowing anything that makes it wrong. I hope someone would correct me so that i can make [the result i wanted to create using the view table query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHC7f.jpg) in my app

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Anyone trying to help you then needs to retype everything. Post clear text.

Comment: i'm very sorry to not know about this, i will correct it right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues:

- In the select part of a select statement, each column you are select needs to return a scalar value. It is not possible to select 3 columns with a single select statement
- It's not possible to reference bind variables (the page item P16_KODE_KAS) in a database object. That doesn't compile because at compilation time, the apex item values cannot be known. Workaround is to use the v() function.
- Use ansi joins instead of the old oracle syntax. It's easier to read and harder to do it wrong.

Here is the "fixed" version. There might still be errors since I have no access to your environment nor table definitions and sample data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "KIR_V_KAS_MASUK_KET" ("...") as
    SELECT
KMH.KODE_KAS,
KA.NIS,
KA.NAMA,
KA.KELAS,
KA.JURUSAN,
(SELECT DISTINCT PERIODE FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD WHERE KODE_KAS=v('P16_KODE_KAS')) PERIODE,
(SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR((SELECT SUM(PEMBAYARAN)  FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL WHERE KODE_KAS = v('P16_KODE_KAS')), '999,999,999') TOTAL_PEMBAYARAN,
(SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(WAJIB_BAYAR * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KIR_ANGGOTA WHERE STATUS != 'TIDAK AKTIF'), '999,999,999') TOTAL_WAJIB_BAYAR,
KMD.KETERANGAN
FROM
KIR_ANGGOTA KA
  JOIN KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL KDM ON KMD.NIS=KA.NIS
  JOIN KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD KMH ON KMD.KODE_KAS=KMH.KODE_KAS
/
```

This being said, it looks like this is only going to be used in a single page. I would not create a view in that case. It looks like overkill.

Comment: i'm sorry it says this but doesn't tell me which line is it
ORA-00921: unexpected end of SQL command

Comment: I had said it: "There might still be errors since I have no access to your environment nor table definitions and sample data.". Remove line by line and try until it works. Then add lines back to see where the error is. Fix error. Basic debugging

Answer (score 2):

What is obvious, is that syntax is wrong. Should be something like this (simplified):

```
create view ... as
select DISTINCT kmh.kode_kas, ...              --> DISTINCT goes here
  (select periode from ... ) periode,
  (select to_char(sum(pembayaran, '999,999,999)) from ...) total_pembayaran
from kir_anggota ka, ...
where ...
```

Note that all subqueries (for `periode`, `total_pembayaran`, ...) **must** return a single value. Their `where` clause have to enforce that.

Comment: https://ibb.co/rbJyMv8 (Error at line 10/45: ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations) CREATE VIEW "KIR_V_KAS_MASUK_KET" (...) as
    SELECT DISTINCT
KMH.KODE_KAS,
KA.NIS,
KA.NAMA,
KA.KELAS,
KA.JURUSAN,
(SELECT PERIODE FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_HEAD WHERE KODE_KAS=:P16_KODE_KAS) PERIODE,
TO_CHAR((SELECT SUM(PEMBAYARAN)  FROM KIR_KAS_MASUK_DETAIL WHERE KODE_KAS = :P16_KODE_KAS), '999,999,999') TOTAL_PEMBAYARAN,
TO_CHAR(WAJIB_BAYAR * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KIR_ANGGOTA WHERE STATUS != 'TIDAK AKTIF'), '999,999,999') TOTAL_WAJIB_BAYAR,
KMD.KETERANGAN

Comment: ERROR in Line 10/45 -> TO_CHAR(WAJIB_BAYAR * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM KIR_ANGGOTA WHERE STATUS != 'TIDAK AKTIF'), '999,999,999') TOTAL_WAJIB_BAYAR,